# Black Screen and too wait one screen to another?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I have a listview in parent activity and I am passing some parameter from parent screen to child activity.Also I have custom  theme and title bar.My question is When I go from parent listview to child view screen, it takes too long time and black screen comes for a while.
What is the reason and how can I avoid it?

I searched in google a bit and also I saw one reason but it did not work for me.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you doing some processing after user clicks on listview item?

Comment: @DuyguK can you please show your code ?

Comment: @DuyguK might some short of code help other to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach to next screen please put your processing task in thread (in OnCreate()) and show progress dialog for waiting.

**Edit -** Try with this theme in activity and let me know what happend.

```
@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
```

Comment: I did it.But i see black screen for a while and after that i see processbar and view.Same problem have other screen too.But it is not always.I am facing sometimes.And Eclipse is not giving any error?

Comment: Hey I have custom titlebar it can be related it?

Comment: @DuyguK may be . Please try to add default and check what happen.

Answer (score 2):

From the description you have a processing problem, not a display problem. You need to identify the routine that is taking too long to complete. Without seeing the processing code it is difficult to recommend a solution.

Here are a few things may help:
Are you running the app on a real device or using the emulator? - The emulator is notoriously slow. Try running it on a real device.

Are you accessing an on-line resource like a web site or web service on the UI thread? All on-line accesses should be run on a dedicated thread.

Where is your processing being done? Do not do excess processing in the onClick of the ListView because it will be run on the UI thread. Place only MINIMAL processing in the onCreate method in the new Activity because this is also run on the UI thread. The best place to put lengthy processing is in the onResume method of the new Activity (this is still run on the UI thread) and ideally pass off the processing to another thread.

Are you accessing a local SQLite database? If so, your SQL statements and/or database may not be optimized for performance. If you are using a local database and are not a strong SQL programmer, ask someone to look at your statements or post them here.

Does your app use a large amount of memory such as large arrays or images loaded into memory? If so, reduce the memory requirements - only hold in memory what you must have at any moment.

If none of these help, please post a detailed description of the processing you do between the onClick of the ListView through to the point where you are ready for another user input.

Comment: I am working real device.Do you know any process viewer in Eclipse for android threads?

Comment: On the Eclipse menu click Window, Show View, Other... Expand Android group, click Devices, select your device. On the button bar of the Devices View click the Update Threads button. On the Eclipse menu, click Window, Show View, Other... In the Android group click Threads.

Do not leave Update Threads turned on to prevent performance degradation. 

An alternative is to place Log.d calls at critical points in your code. Messages appear on the LogCat view. Log.d has less impact on performance and the messages are timestamped.